# What is the easiest way to hide HTML code from users eye?

Tags: java, html, jsp, comments

I am currently working with JSP pages and would like to know what would be the easiest way to comment HTML/Java code from being able to see it when you open source on the web. As for now, I was used to use

```
<%-- html/Java code --%>
```

However, later on it screw up all highlighting of JSP file. Maybe there is another way of commenting multiple lines without possibility to see them in HTML source on web.

Comment: Use <%--  hidden code --%>

Comment: "However, later on it screw up all highlighting of JSP file" I am not sure what you mean here. What problem exactly you are trying to solve?

Comment: @MaxZoom `<!-- -->` This comment will be sent to client (browser). `<%-- --%>` prevents it.

Comment: When we use <!-- --> users still can see hidden code. I want to prevent it. However, since I am using Notepad++, <%-- --%> syntax messes up all highlighting of JSP file later on. So I want to know if there is other way to prevent users from seeing HTML code (when they open source in web). If not, how could I add <%-- --%> syntax to be recognized in notepad as a comment

Comment: I would suggest changing your editor to IDE like Ecplise, NetBeans, Intellij.

Comment: Looks like we have to move to new tool. Thank you for idea.

Answer (score 3):

**Look:**

```
<%-- Comment --%>  - commenting out html

<% /*java code*/ %>  - commenting out java code  

<!-- comment --> - html comment, ignored by the browser
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to quote Oracle on this one: [Code Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/code-convention-138726.html)

Please note the following (excerpt from the link):

1. JSP comments (also called server-side comments) are visible only on the server side (that is, not propagated to the client side). Pure JSP comments are preferred over JSP comments with scripting language comments, as the former is less dependent on the underlying scripting language, and will be easier to evolve into JSP 2.0-style pages.

Examples:

```
<% /** ... */ %>
<% /* ... */ %>
<% //... %>
<% //... %>
```

- Client-side comments can be used to annotate the responses sent to the client with additional information about the responses. They should not contain information about the behavior and internal structure of the server application or the code to generate the responses.

Let's note that these comments:

```
<!-- ... -->
```

ignore all elements except @import statements.